# Query mysql database before webpack

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, webpack, browser

I have info in mysql. In simple terms I want to get that info, create a bundled file.js using webpack and finally run that script in frontend browser.

Currently I get that info, create a new temp.js file with that info and then run webpack getting the info from that file, but I dont like the idea of creating a new temporal file when running webpack.